# How can I preserve / enforce formatting when converting a Markdown file to pdf?

Tags: pdf, mkdocs

How can I convert a Markdown file to PDF and preserve the code block formatting?

The Markdown code

```
JSON
{
  "client_id": "string",
  "api_key": "string",
  "data": {
```

as served up via Mkdocs looks like:

**EX_1**

[image]

After converting the Markdown file to PDF (or docx, etc.), the formatting looks like this:

**EX_2**

[image]

I need to preserve the background color and the line numbering illustrated in EX_1.

Comment: No, the images were added here to illustrate the difference in output. I'll update the issue with the code snippet.

Comment: Ah I get it. I edited your input to the top, and only then what it looks like in your editor. That makes things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may run into a similar issue the following fixed the issue for me;

1. Create a file named preamble.tex
2. Add the following to the file and save: `\usepackage{longtable}\setlength{\LTleft}{0em}`
3. Run your pan doc command; `pandoc test.md -o test.pdf -H preamble.tex`